# How to find Sum at Each partition in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, partitioning

I have created class and used that class to create RDD. I want to calculate sum of **LoudnessRate** (member of class) at each partition. This sum will be later used to calculate Mean **LoudnessRate** at each partition.
I have tried following code but it does not calculate Sum and returns **0.0**.
My code is

```scala
    object sparkBAT {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val numPartitions = 3
        val N = 50
        val d = 5
        val MinVal = -10
        val MaxVal =  10
        val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(locally("local")).setAppName("spark Sum")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

        val ba = List.fill(N)(new BAT(d, MinVal, MaxVal))
        val rdd = sc.parallelize(ba, numPartitions)

        var arrSum =Array.fill(numPartitions)(0.0) // Declare Array that will hold sum for each Partition
        rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((k,iterator) => iterator.map(x => arrSum(k) += x.LoudnessRate)).collect()
        arrSum foreach println
      }
    }


    class BAT (dim:Int, min:Double, max:Double) extends Serializable {    
      val random = new Random()
      var position      : List[Double]      =   List.fill(dim) (random.nextDouble() * (max-min)+min )
      var velocity      :List[Double]       =   List.fill(dim)( math.random)
      var PulseRate     : Double            =   0.1
      var LoudnessRate  :Double             =   0.95
      var frequency     :Double             =   math.random
      var fitness       :Double             =   math.random
      var BestPosition  :List[Double]       =   List.fill(dim)(math.random)
      var BestFitness   :Double             =   math.random 
    }
```

Comment: You are modifying `arrSum` in executor JVMs and printing its values in the dirver JVM. You can map the iterators to singleton iterators and use `collect` to move the values to the driver. Also, don't use `iterator.map` for side-effects, `iterator.foreach` is meant for that

Comment: @ollik1 This should be an answer (if you add the code).

Comment: @ollik1 can you please add code?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov and yari, Fair enough, added the code as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing my comment to an answer as requested. Original comment

> You are modifying arrSum in executor JVMs and printing its values in the dirver JVM. You can map the iterators to singleton iterators and use collect to move the values to the driver. Also, don't use iterator.map for side-effects, iterator.foreach is meant for that.

And here is a sample snippet how to do it. First creating a RDD with two partitions, `0 -> 1,2,3` and `1 -> 4,5`. Naturally you would not need this in actual code but as the `sc.parallelize` behaviour changes depending on environment, this will always create uniform RDDs to reproduce:

```
object DemoPartitioner extends Partitioner {
  override def numPartitions: Int = 2
  override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = key match {
    case num: Int => num
  }
}
val rdd = sc
  .parallelize(Seq((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)))
  .partitionBy(DemoPartitioner)
  .map(_._2)
```

And then the actual trick:

```
val sumsByPartition = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  case (partitionNum, it) => Iterator.single(partitionNum -> it.sum)
}.collect().toMap
println(sumsByPartition)
```

Outputs:

```
Map(0 -> 6, 1 -> 9)
```

Comment: This gives the desired result as i needed. one more question, is this optimal way to calculate sum or can we do more optimizations? with respect to speed

Comment: I'd say in most cases it is pretty much the fastest way to calculate the sum per partition (which itself is not that common operation using Spark). There is no shuffle between the executors which is often the slow part and only minimalistic data is sent over network to be collected to driver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using arrSum (a regular collection) that is declared in your Driver and updated in the Executors. Whenever you're doing that you need to use Accumulators.

[This](https://medium.com/@shrechak/leveraging-custom-accumulators-in-apache-spark-2-0-f4fef23f19f1) should help